# what are the differences between df1[:100]['comb'] and df1['comb?

Tags: python, pandas, row, slice

Here is what I ran into and can't understand why.
I have a few lines of code

```
tstr = df1[:100]['comb'].str.cat(sep=' ')
```

It worked fine.
However, when I drop the row slice, see below,

```
tstr = df1['comb'].str.cat(sep=' ')
```

it got an error from later processing, not this line.
My DF has only 100 rows, so technically [:100] should have no effect.
I found this problem because I initially limited to 10 rows for work out the code.
while the error points to later code, the cause has to be the drop of slice.

I wonder what are the differences between these two lines of code when the row number is 100.
thanks.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: `"it got an error from later processing, not this line"` What was this error?

Comment: There are processing before and after the line. When i submitted, somehow, those notes were dropped. So this question appears to be out of context.

Comment: The error is really hard to explain. involving converting one column to a single string, then do a web call. So I'm not sure is at string conversion part of after web call processing. Sorry that much of detail won't worth your time.

Comment: @Xixi As per the details provided by you, the only solution is to print `tstr` and check if both are same. Without exact error or relevant details its difficult to find the problem. If problem is in some other line due to this change, you have to provide that. Also please check [how to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you all for comments. The error points to later part of processing, which makes a POST call to a third party site and returns way too much data to examine or print to actually find the culprit.

Comment: As @ShivendraPratapKushwaha said, you need to print `tstr` and compare the differences. If the slicing in this line is truly the cause of the later error, then there must be a difference in `tstr`. Often bugs occur when we assume something to be true that isn't actually true (e.g. maybe there's some case where `df1` is not 100 rows like you thought, or some other unexpected issue). You are the only one who can provide the necessary debugging information by logging `tstr` in your code.